# How to correctly get phase of a complex number

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, angle

If  $z = -99.75 + 3i $   is a complex number.

How can I calculate the Argument of $z$?

I tried $$\arctan\left(\frac{3}{99.75}\right) = 1.72°$$
but if I try to compute it on wolfram the result is 178.712° (that should be correct) how do I get here?

Comment: The argument of a complex number, $\theta$, satisfies the two relations$$|z|\cos{(\theta)}=\Re{(z)}\quad|z|\sin{(\theta)}=\Im{(z)}$$which implies that $\tan{(\theta)}=\Im{(z)}/\Re{(z)}$ but isn't equivalent to this statement.

Comment: See this Wikipedia entry: [atan2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2)

Comment: @stevengregory but wikipedai says to do arctan(y/x) + pi = 1.72+180 = 181.72 that is not the correct result

Comment: Not quite: the arctangent is negative.

Comment: $y=3,x=-99.75$ here, so you need to take $\arctan(-3/99.75)$, you can't ignore the sign.

Comment: but i have always to consider the - if there is one ?

Comment: Of course, the complex number $-2+3\iota$ corresponds to the point $(-2,3)$ in the $x-y$ plane, but $2+3\iota$ corresponds to a different point $(2,3)$.

Comment: @Marià Did you use a negative number for $x$?

Comment: Using the Wolfram language try `Arg[-99.75+3I]180/Pi` which evaluates to `178.277`. That is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$z=-99.75+3\iota$ is the point $P(-99.75,3)$ in the $x-y$ plane, which is in the $2^{nd}$ quadrant, so the angle $AP$ ($A$ is the origin) is making with the positive $x-$axis (which is defined as $\arg(z)$), is $$90^\circ+\angle CAP=90^\circ+\arctan\left(\dfrac{CP}{CA}\right)=90^\circ+\arctan\left(\dfrac{99.75}3\right)\approx 178.28^\circ$$

[image]

$\arg(z)$ is usually defined modulo $180^\circ$, i.e. depending on the location of $z$, the angle the vector $\vec{Az}$ (formed by joining the origin to the point $z$) makes with the positive $x-$axis, measured in the counter-clockwise direction (positive angle) or clockwise direction (negative angle), whichever gives the least absolute value.

Comment: Why are we doin 90+arctan ?

Comment: $\arg(z)\in(-\pi,\pi]$ is defined as the angle made by the vector $\vec{Oz}$, where $O$ is the origin, with the positive $x-$axis. In this case, $\arg(z)$ is a positive angle (measured counterclockwise) that is $<180^\circ$. We want to measure that angle. After that it's trigonometry in the right-angled $\triangle CAP$. 
This is a safe process to arrive at the right answer because the range of $\arctan(x)$ is $\left[-\frac{\pi}2,\frac{\pi}2\right]$, but the range of $\arg{z},z\in\Bbb{C}$ is $(-\pi,\pi]$. The link in the comment by @steven gregory up in your post will help you too.

Comment: But when we said is  ∈(−π,π) it means that is only defined in the lower quadrants ?

Comment: $$\arg{z}\in(-\pi,0)\implies z\in\text{ lower quadrants} \\ \arg{z}\in(0,\pi)\implies z\in\text{ upper quadrants} \\ \arg{z}=0\implies z\in\text{ positive x-axis}\\ \arg{z}=\pi \implies z\in\text{ negative x-axis} $$ so all possible positions of $z$ are considered.